# How to handle OutOfMemoryError when loading large bitmap without loss in quality?

Tags: java, android

I am using chrisbanes's photoview library for zoomable images. https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView

Image i am trying to load has 2000x2000 resolution. 
Simply, I first load the bitmap, then I draw something to the bitmap I loaded. then I load the bitmap to the imageview. I need to manipulate the source image differently for each use, so I need to create a bitmap to create a canvas. But at line where creating bitmaps, in some devices the app throws outOfMemoryException. I check the logs and the original bitmap size is 5250x5250 and creating another bitmap with same size drains a lot of memory i think.

I have tried loading bitmap with BitmapFactory.Options, i used inSampleSize but it degraded the image.

```
PhotoView imageView;

Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.test_image);

Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setColor(Color.RED);
paint.setAntiAlias(true);

Bitmap tempBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(),bitmap.getHeight(),Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);

Canvas canvas = new Canvas(tempBitmap);

canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap,0,0,null);

paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
paint.setStrokeWidth(4);

//drawing operations, like
//canvas.drawCircle(tempX,tempY,tempRadius,paint);
//canvas.drawLine(firstX,firstY,secondX,secondY,paint);

imageView.setImageDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),tempBitmap));
```

Since i use photoview, the imageview is zoomable and i need the image is well detailed even if fully zoomed but using inSampleSize regrades the image. I want it to be memory efficient and smooth as possible.

Comment: Welcome to SO! I am confused - has it now 2000x2000 or 5250x5250 pixel?

Comment: Use something like [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) to handle image loading for you.

Comment: @TheWanderer That won't help at all.  His problem is it uses up too much memory period.  5250x5250x4=  100MB.  That will bust the Java heap on all but the most recent devices.  And that's not including extra memory needed while decoding.  The real answer is not to use such a large image in the first place.

Comment: @GabeSechan they're trying to load it at 2000x2000. I'm pretty sure Picasso loads large images in chunks to avoid OOM.

Comment: @TheWanderer  He later says 5250.  And 2kx2k is still 16 MB, a signigicant amount, depending on what else his app is doing.  Picasso doesn not have a magic technology that makes a Bitmap object take less than 4 bytes per pixel undecoded.  I doubt it even has its own decoder to make the uncompression more efficient (it most likely uses inSampleSize), but it absolutely cannot improve the output.

Comment: @dr0i the image in resources has 2000x2000 resolution, the bitmap decoded from resource has 5250 width and height

Comment: @TheWanderer I need to manipulate the source image differently for each use, so I need to create a bitmap to create a canvas. I couldn't achieve this with Picasso am i missing something

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use [Subsampling Scale Image View](https://github.com/davemorrissey/subsampling-scale-image-view) for the purpose of processing large images without encountering the **OutOfMemoryError**. As recommended by others, it's not recommend to use large images but this should assist you achieve the functionality you desire.

> The view optionally uses subsampling and tiles to support very large images - a low resolution base layer is loaded and as you zoom in, it is overlaid with smaller high resolution tiles for the visible area. This avoids holding too much data in memory. It's ideal for displaying large images while allowing you to zoom in to the high resolution details. You can disable tiling for smaller images and when displaying a bitmap object.

The important thing about this I want to point is: -

> Tested up to 20,000x20,000px, though larger images are slower